# I need help understanding why my if statement is executing

Tags: string, if-statement, execute, operation

I am having a hard time understanding why my first if statement is executing if my string variable exam1ScoreKnown is assigned the string "YES" or "Y". I only want the if statement to execute if the string is anything other than "YES" or "Y". Also, I have checked to make sure the variable is assigned "YES" or "Y" right before the if statement.

```
if (exam1ScoreKnown != "YES" || exam1ScoreKnown != "Y") {
        totalWeight = totalWeight - exam1Weight - exam2Weight - finalExamWeight;
}
else if (exam2ScoreKnown != "YES" || exam2ScoreKnown != "Y") {
        totalWeight = totalWeight - exam2Weight - finalExamWeight;
}
else if (finalExamScoreKnown != "YES" || finalExamScoreKnown != "Y") {
        totalWeight = totalWeight - finalExamWeight;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This Boolean expression

```
(exam1ScoreKnown != "YES" || exam1ScoreKnown != "Y")
```

is equivalent to

```
!(exam1ScoreKnown == "YES" && exam1ScoreKnown == "Y")
```

I think in this rewritten form it is easier to see that it is a tautology, ie it is true every which way.  I think you need to replace the `or` by `and`.